# zsh alias with arguements

Tags: zsh, alias

I have an alias for `neovim-qt` thus defined:

```
gvim='nvim-qt --geometry 500x320 --'
```

This allows me to call `gvim foo.py ook.py` and have a QT window running `neovim` with two tabs, one for each file.

However, this does return me to the prompt of the shell. I have to add a `&` at the end of the command line. Since I am lazy and forgetful, I keep not doing `ctrl+z` and `bg` which is irritating. I want to add a `&` after all other arguments in the alias.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do anything more complex than to replace a simple command with an alias, use a shell function.

In your case:

```
function gvim {
    nvim-qt --geometry 500x320 -- "$@" &
}
```

Aliases are not really suited for much more than simple things, like adding your favourite flags to `ls` or whatever.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what if I also want to "detach" the process from the terminal that spawned it? So that I can close the terminal and keep on editing the file in `nvim-qt`. Using `"$@" & disown` does not seem to work (I remember doing that for `gvim` a long time ago). Is there any other way?

Comment: @Stunts Unfortunately I don't have access to this version of Vim (I actually do not run X11 on my machines at all) so I don't quite know how it behaves. GVim shouldn't need `&` nor `disown` as it detaches by default, if I remember correctly.